# Is there a way to access the current iteration count as an Int in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, loops

When I need to go through a list of items and update each one, I normally use a for loop like this:

```
for budget in arrayOfBudgets {
   budget.rent = enteredRentAmount
}
```

But when I need to access an index during the loop, I do something more like this:

```
for index in 0..<arrayOfBudgets.count {
   arrayOfBudgets[index].rent = enteredAmounts[index]
}
```

My question is, is it possible to combine those 2 methods and do something like this?:

```
for budget in arrayOfBudgets {
   budget.rent = enteredAmounts[currentIterationCount] // currentIterationCount would be equal to 0 on first loop iteration, 1 on second iteration, and so on
}
```

I know it's easy enough to do this workaround:

```
var index = 0
for budget in arrayOfBudgets {
   budget.rent = enteredAmounts[index]
   index += 1
}
```

But I don't like the 2 extra lines of code and the `index` variable just sitting there forever after the loop is done, so I'm hoping there's a way to gain access to the iteration count of loops in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`enumerate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated) the array

```
for (index, budget) in arrayOfBudgets.enumerated() {
   budget.rent = enteredAmounts[index]
}
```

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thank you.